# How to handle virtual environments on a secure network

Tags: virtualization

We do embedded software development.  As such, we use a wide variety of tool sets for the many different targets that we work with, and we frequently move from one project to the next.  Developers will move between projects often.

We have serious issues with configuration management.  We have build machines in labs with "do not touch" stickers on them in case we need to go back in six months and rebuild some software.  Development workstations wind up with an extremely wide variety of software installed after enough project switches, leading to compatibility issues.  Often, some setup will only work on Ubuntu or Windows or RHEL - leading to more confusion.

I had thought that virtual machines may be a solution to this problem.  Let developers "check out" a pre-setup virtual environment to do their work in, and switch to another one when they switch projects.  Archive virgin images of our build machines to ensure we can reproduce builds down the line.  The problem is with security.  IT requirements say that only Windows 7 and RHEL machines that are fully updated can be connected to our network.  This means that for things like Ubuntu environments, we cannot even access license servers or source control systems.  They are also concerned about issues of controlling sprawl- letting a dev fire up a bunch of VM's on his desktop.  One solution to this would be to invest in a large VM server that everyone can remote into, but this seems like it would be pretty wasteful of all the machines hanging around the building.

What I am really interested in is how you handle this issue in a secure network environment?

Comment: It's time for configuration management: Puppet, chef, salt, ansible, _something_!

Comment: Have you looked at Vagrant (www.vagrantup.com)?

Comment: You've got some problems if your dev environment only runs in ubuntu, requires a license server on your network, and only fully updated RHEL & Windows installs are allowed on the network. As the saying goes, Pick Two. You're also likely to find that if you keep them updated, it's *going* to break your build down the road when some upstream changes a library API you use after it has passed QC and you've shipped it. Another vote for Puppet and add qemu on qcow2 w/ snapshotting. You get a portable disk image you can archive on tape and/or offsite and the ability to keep differential copies.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the management software, but that's not actually what I'm asking.  There is a ton of technology to handle these problems- but our IT organization doesn't like the idea of any of them.  I am more wondering how to overcome their objections so that we can use vagrant or qemu with puppet.